# Center through CSS doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I have div in HTML, there is i Picture and a piece of text. I have all this center through margin, but it is all in left. Why? 
HTML:

```
<div class="slozka">
    <img src="http://randompics.net/gmig6jx/" alt="složka"></br>
    {{object}}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slozka
{
    width:125px;
    padding:0px
}
.slozka > img
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}
.slozka:hover
{
    border-style: outset;
}
```

Comment: `</br>`? You have no start tag for it, and the end tag is forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to provide "`text-align: center;`" to "`.slozka{...}`" class

Answer (score 4):

Auto margins centre block elements. That image is `display: inline` (the default).

Set `.slizka { text-align: center; }` instead (this centres inline content).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to center `.slozka` also.

```
.slozka
{
    width:125px;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also if `</br>` is supposed to be a line break then it is in correct, you need `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

```
use this
.slozka { text-align: center; }
```